# update mysql using php does not work

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-update

I am trying to update my database table inside a foreach loop but it doesn't seem to work

I dont know where is the problem or what am doing wrong.

```
foreach($ids as $id_number=>$id)
{
    $request = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=".$id."";
    $response = file_get_contents($request); 
    $ok = json_decode($response,true);/*print_r($ok);*/
    foreach($ok as $p)
    {
        $location=$p['location'];
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE tweets SET location=$location 
                        WHERE from_user_id=$id");
    }
    if($query)
        echo'ok';
    else
        echo'no';
}
```

It will be helpful if someone knows another way of doing this!

Comment: where and when do you check for PHP or MySQL errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `'$location'` instead of `$location` :

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE tweets SET location='$location' 
                    WHERE from_user_id=$id");
```

keep in mind that The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, it's better to use `MySQLi` or `PDO`

instead

Comment: thank you.now working with the '$location'. i was using ".$location." this before

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated, the PHP community recommends the use of either MySQLi or PDO to work with MySQL. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php for more info.

Comment: Note: The mysql_* are not deprecated! They are no longer recommended and a future deprecation has been announced (no date set) but let's not confuse this with active deprecation and no strict deprecation errors will be thrown. E_DEPRECATED errors *may* be thrown as of 5.5 or 5.6, but to my knowledge this hasn't been decided yet. Regardless, point is well taken than people should stop using this extension.